# Extracting data from .txt and writing to .txt with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to code the following problem using python. Suppose we have the following data set in a .txt file:

```
datatype1 designator1 3:45:14AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:19AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:26AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:31AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:05AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:21AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:30AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:46AM
```

Note the time break. I need my code to read through the text file and, where there is a break in the time intervals, split the file up and write the following to another text file:

```
datatype1 designator1 3:45:14AM 3:45:31AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:05AM 4:10:46AM
```

In other words, I want to condense the original data to individual "sessions" represented by single lines with start and end times.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start and end times by hour you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Perform the following steps:

- Parse each line, extract the time
- From each time, convert it to a date/time structure
- Check against the previous date/time structure (if any)
- If the difference is bigger than some predefined value, start a new file
- write the complete line

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
file_data = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]
final_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(file_data, key=lambda x:':'.join(x[-1].split(':')[:2]))]
new_final_data = [' '.join([' '.join(b[0][:-1]), ' '.join([b[0][-1], b[-1][-1]])]) for _, b in final_data]
print(new_final_data)
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
   f.write('\n'.join(new_final_data))
```

Output:

```
['datatype1 designator1 3:45:14AM 3:45:31AM', 'datatype1 designator1 4:10:05AM 4:10:46AM']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas this task becomes more readable:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''\
datatype1 designator1 3:30:14AM
datatype1 designator1 3:30:18AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:14AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:19AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:26AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:31AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:05AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:21AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:30AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:46AM'''


# Recreate dataset
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep='\s+', header=None)

# Use this instead of above for real file
#df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file',sep='\s+', header=None)

# Get first and last by hour (convert to dt)
df[2] = sorted(pd.to_datetime(df[2]))
newdf = df.groupby((df[2].dt.hour, df[2].dt.minute // 15)).agg(['first', 'last'])

# Rename columns and drop duplicates
newdf.columns = list(range(len(newdf.columns)))
newdf.drop(newdf.columns[[1,3]], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Format time
newdf[[4,5]] = newdf[[4,5]].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%#H:%M:%S%p'))

# Output
print(newdf.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False, sep=' '))
```

output.csv:

```
datatype1 designator1 3:30:14AM 3:30:18AM
datatype1 designator1 3:45:14AM 3:45:31AM
datatype1 designator1 4:10:05AM 4:10:46AM
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. One minor tweak: there are many instances in the data in which there are multiple 'sessions' within the span of an hour. What's the best way of modifying the code you provided to accommodate that? My initial thought was to use an 'if' statement, something like "if time (i + 1) - i > 15 minutes, then cut off and start a new session. (i = index)

Comment: @Vincent Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Vincent I'm gonna guess you want to have 15 min windows: You can pass another variable to groupby that is the div of every 15 min (so 0,1,2,3) . Or maybe you want to cut iteratively?